# wysihtml5 Parser Issue using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg

I have using the standard parser that wysihtml5 bootstrap supplies it is just that the links do not come up with the right href attribute. How do I change this using the parser that they give you.

Using scripts...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<script src="js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js"></script>
```

Parser Source: https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/blob/master/parser_rules/advanced.js

Parser exerpt:

```
* The following options are available:
 *
 *    - add_class:        converts and deletes the given HTML4 attribute (align, clear, ...) via the given method to a css class
 *                        The following methods are implemented in wysihtml5.dom.parse:
 *                          - align_text:  converts align attribute values (right/left/center/justify) to their corresponding css class "wysiwyg-text-align-*")
 *                            <p align="center">foo</p> ... becomes ... <p> class="wysiwyg-text-align-center">foo</p>
 *                          - clear_br:    converts clear attribute values left/right/all/both to their corresponding css class "wysiwyg-clear-*"
 *                            <br clear="all"> ... becomes ... <br class="wysiwyg-clear-both">
 *                          - align_img:    converts align attribute values (right/left) on <img> to their corresponding css class "wysiwyg-float-*"
 *                          
 *    - remove:             removes the element and its content
 *
 *    - rename_tag:         renames the element to the given tag
 *
 *    - set_class:          adds the given class to the element (note: make sure that the class is in the "classes" white list above)
 *
 *    - set_attributes:     sets/overrides the given attributes
 *
 *    - check_attributes:   checks the given HTML attribute via the given method
 *                            - url:            allows only valid urls (starting with http:// or https://)
 *                            - src:            allows something like "/foobar.jpg", "http://google.com", ...
 *                            - href:           allows something like "mailto:bert@foo.com", "http://google.com", "/foobar.jpg"
 *                            - alt:            strips unwanted characters. if the attribute is not set, then it gets set (to ensure valid and compatible HTML)
 *                            - numbers:  ensures that the attribute only contains numeric characters
    "a": {
        "check_attributes": {
            "href": "href"
        },
        "set_attributes": {
            "rel": "nofollow",
            "target": "_blank"
        }
    },
```

So basically what I am trying to do is take all of the a tags and set their href attribute to their contents. or disable the parser's tendency to delete my href attributes. Could it be a bug?